# webpack - MiniCssExtractPlugin set absolute path for .css file

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, plugins

remove relative URLs and use absolute URLs in CSS imports.

webpack code -

```
 new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
        }),
```

bundle file in html is

this is relative path but i want to set abosolute path to this .css url from webpack config file using  MiniCssExtractPlugin

Impact
An attacker may trick browsers into importing JavaScript or HTML code as a stylesheet. This has been shown to enable a number of different attacks, including
cross-site scripting (XSS) and exfiltration of CSRF tokens.

webpack.config file

```
/* eslint-disable global-require */
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackCleanupPlugin = require('webpack-cleanup-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const webpackBundleAnalyzer = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    target: 'web',
    entry: {
        bundle: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.jsx'),
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules\/(?!objectmodel).+/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                resolve: {
                    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(s[ac]ss|css)$/i,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: { sourceMap: true },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: { sourceMap: true },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            plugins: () => [require('cssnano')],
                            sourceMap: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(pdf|ico|png|jpg|svg)$/,
                use: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[ext]',
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new WebpackCleanupPlugin(),
        new webpackBundleAnalyzer.BundleAnalyzerPlugin({ analyzerMode: 'static' }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            favicon: 'src/favicon.ico',
            template: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html'),
            minify: {
                removeComments: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                keepClosingSlash: true,
                minifyJS: true,
                minifyCSS: true,
                minifyURLs: true,
            },
        }),
    ],
};
```

Comment: What builds your htmls? is it `html-webpack-plugin`?

Comment: Yes @felixmosh i am using const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

Answer (score 0):

You can change your [`output.publicPath`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputpublicpath) to the absolute prefix, it will change all of your assets (in html, in css) to be prefixed with it.

```
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
  publicPath: 'https://my-cdn.com/',
  filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
},
```